# CyanogenMod: Low volume parts of songs are not played (muted)

Tags: cyanogenmod, audio, music, music-player

I have troubles with playing music on Samsung Galaxy S2 with CyanogenMod 10.

When I play music to headphones with low volume, playing music is really influent. It seems like playing is being stopped in quiet parts of song.

I tried a lot of music players and it's always the same. Is there any help? It isn't very much comfortable to listen music in such situation.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem for a long time now. It's really annoying. Updated and reinstalled the ROM several times in between - doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a [common hardware problem](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35861) on Samsung devices.

Easiest solution is to just install the newest [Dorimanx kernel](http://dorimanx.shine.sk/) for Samsung Galaxy SII. Works for me now.

Source: This thread [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/73718-sound-switches-off-below-a-certain-volume/).

Answer (score -1):

You have to flash a volume driver. You will get from the link where you downloaded the custom rom.

Your new custom rom is not supporting the default driver. You can flash the zip file from the app you got by default in a new rom like cmw.

Comment: Never heard about such thing. Can you give a reference for this "something"?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a link to a forum or other page that explains this problem and the solution. As it stands, your answer is too vague.